# How can I find an element with XPath using its parent?

Tags: xpath

I need to get the "a" element inside a "td" element from a row in a table of several similar rows. The problem is I only have the name 'john'. How can I find john td -> get the parent "tr" -> and then get "a" in XPath?

Code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <table>
    ...
    <tr id='1'>
      <td name='john'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id='clickable'/>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do :

```
//*[@name="john"]/../td/a/@id
```

Comment: I mark this as the correct one because it will help me in other use cases.

Answer (score 5):

I would write this XPath expression like this:

```
//td[@name="john"]/following-sibling::td[1]/a
```

This does:

- `//`

  - from any depth
- `td`

  - find a `td` element
- `[@name="john"]`

  - with a `name` attribute equal to `'john'`
- `/following-sibling::`

  - now look among its following sibling elements
- `td`

  - and find another `td`
- `[1]`

  - get the first one
- `/a`

  - and get its children that are `a` elements

Comment: This is probably the most robust answer for scraping the given HTML.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
//a[ancestor::tr[td/@name = 'john']]
```